# TypeError: Cannot read property 'tid' of undefined(…)

Tags: javascript-remoting, remote-action

I have created a RemoteAction in controller and trying to access get the records from using this method is JavaScript.

Previously the code was working perfectly but all of sudden it started throwing javascript error as

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'tid' of undefined(…)

I cannot post the code here because its a very long code developed in Angular, As this was working previously I am pretty much sure this has nothing to do with Angular.js.

Has anyone faced this kind of situation? Please guide me to get through this.

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: when you said it works well previously, have you modify the code recently?If you done nothing , it may due to version.